# Duplicate asynchronous component twice render the last

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I create the same component (**Recipes**) or Screen twice, sending different properties.

```
<Recipes setRecipes = {this.setRecipes} id="1" />
<Quantity setQuantity = {this.setQuantity} />
<Recipes setRecipes = {this.setRecipes2} id="2" />
<Quantity setQuantity = {this.setQuantity} />
```

The properties-functions are the following. Only states change.

```
setRecipes = (recipe) => {
    this.setState({recipe:recipe})

  }

  setRecipes2 = (recipe2) => {
    this.setState({recipe2:recipe2})

  }
```

In mty component called **Recipes**, I get my local database (I use pouchdb), my recipes and products asicronically.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import style from './Styles/styleNew';
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb-react-native';

PouchDB.plugin(require('pouchdb-find'));



const gThis = null;
const db = new PouchDB('X')

export default class Recipes extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      gThis = this;
      this.state = {
         setRecipes: this.props.setRecipes,
         id: this.props.id,
         recipeID: null,
         options: [ ],
      };
   }


   getRecipes() {
      let data = []
      db.find({
         selector: {
            type: {
               "$eq": this.state.id,
            },
            owner: {
               "$in": ['user']
            },
         },

      }).then(function (recipes) {
         recipes = recipes.docs

         for (let i = 0; i < recipes.length; i++) {

            recipe = recipes[i]   

            let current = {
               id: recipe._id,
               name: recipe.name,
               recipe: recipe,
            }
            data.push(current)

         }
         gThis.setState({ options: data })


      }).catch(function (err) {
         console.warn(err.toString())
      });
   }

   componentDidMount() {
      this.getRecipes()
   }




   handleBackPress = () => {
      this.props.navigation.goBack();
   }

   defineRecipe(recipe, index) {
      this.setState({ recipeID: recipe._id });
      this.state.setRecipes(recipe)
   }

   render() {



      return (

         <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Text style={style.listText}>RECIPES {this.state.id} </Text>
            <ScrollView style={style.listScroll}>

               {this.state.options.length >0 &&
                  this.state.options.map((item, index) => {
                     key = index + '-' + this.state.id
                     //key = new Date().toISOString()
                     console.log(key)
                     return (
                        <TouchableOpacity
                           style={this.state.recipeID === item.id ? style.listOptionSelected : style.listOption}
                           onPress={() => { this.defineRecipe(item.recipe, index);}}
                           key={key} >
                           <Text style={style.listOptionText}>{item.name}</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                     );
                  })
               }
            </ScrollView>
         </View>
      );
   }
}
```

But the second Screen Recipe is rendered twice.

1. [Render 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqecV.jpg)
2. [Render 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYKmT.jpg)

As you can see, the content is replaced.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might have something to do with you gThis which I assume is a global this?

A better way to try and access this inside your class members is to either use lexical arrow functions in your class like this:

```
getRecipes = () => {
  // implementation   
}
```

Or bind your class members to this in the constructor as follows

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  gThis = this;
  this.state = {
      id: this.props.id,
      recipeID: null,
      options: [ ],
  };

  this.getRecipes = this.getRecipes.bind(this);
  this.defineRecipe = this.defineRecipe.bind(this);
}
```

On a different node, you have babel transpiling your ES6 code from as far as I can see. 
I would strongly recommend replacing your for loops with es6 variants such as a map or forEach for readability

```
const options = recipes.map(recipe => {
  const { _id: id, name } = recipe;
  data.push({
    id,
    name,
    recipe,
  });
});

this.setState({ options });
```